# Creating a playlist out of songs from selected artists

Tags: android, search, sd-card, playlist, audio-player, android-music-player

I am working on some code that receives a list of artists and needs to search the SD card in order to create a playlist out of specified artists' songs. Can you guys give me some tips/examples on how to acomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at [MediaStore.Audio](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and also for anyone that may come here and still need help: All the info about the music on the phone is actually stored in a database with columns like MediaStore.Audio.Media.Artist and the like. The rest is just the matter of querying!